# Does Tomcat need to be restarted after a JDK is updated?

Tags: java, tomcat

If Tomcat is started with a JAVA_HOME of:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jre
```

which is itself a symlink to something like:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-1.7.0.80.x86_64/jre
```

and then Java is updated while Tomcat is running to:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-1.7.0.95.x86_64/jre
```

with the previous symlink now pointing to the new Java location on the file system does Tomcat need to be restarted after the update?

I believe I've seen problems without a restart related to class loading but I'm looking for references to best practices, instructions, or guidelines either for or against the need to restart.  My google-fu is failing me on finding a definitive answer to this.

Added 3/30/2106:
We just saw this on our Jenkins server after the JVM was updated with Tomcat runing to java-1.7.0-oracle-1.7.0.99.x86_64. The stack trace ended with:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-oracle-1.7.0.95.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(URLClassPath.java:726)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.access$600(URLClassPath.java:591)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:673)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:666)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(URLClassPath.java:665)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:836)
```

Comment: tomcat's filehandles will be pointing at the previous version of whatever java files it was using. unless tomcat itself checks to see if a relevant file has been changed behind its back like this, it'll just keep using those "stale" file pointers until it's restarted.

Answer (score 2):

In general, your JVM processes should not have to be restarted after you upgrade the JVM. However, I have had at least one case where a production server whose JVM was upgraded started acting funny within about 24 hours. It suddenly couldn't find certain resources on the disk.

To be safe, I would arrange to bounce your Tomcat instances if you are going to upgrade the JVM.

As for the symlink, that shouldn't be a problem at all. If you have two (or more) JVMs installed side-by-side, then installing a new version and changing the symlink shouldn't have any effect on a running server. In my case, I had upgraded the JVM through the OS's package-manager, which actually replaced the old one with a new one.

Comment: I faced the same issue with Jenkins after Open JDK upgrade. It was solved after a restart.